# My SQL Server corrupted information_schema after import

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and created a set of tables/stored procedures using `aspnet_regsql`.

I believe that my database is corrupted after an import. I have stored procedures in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and there is only few stored procedures under `Programmability > Stored Procedures`, those are asp net procedures created using the `aspnet_regsql` and now I can´t recreate because SQL Server says the the object already exists.

How can I fix that?

Thanks

P.S I have performed a automatically export/import from one remote database to another.

Comment: I doubt that it's actually corrupted. It sounds more like there's some issue preventing you from *seeing* the procedures which are there. Have you tried restarting Management Studio? (actually, Object Explorer caches information - a refresh may be all that's required)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I had a backup I just had my database imported again.

thanks